# Why does my native application compiled on Apple Silicon sometimes build as arm64 and sometimes build as x86_64?

Tags: c++, c, macos, native, apple-silicon

I have a basic C program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
}
```

When I compile this directly using `cc` on an Apple Silicon device, it produces an `arm64` executable:

```
% cc hello.c -o hello

% file hello
hello: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64

% ./hello
Hello, world!
```

However, when I build it through a build system such as CMake or Ninja, it produces an x86_64 binary:

```
% ./my-build-system

% file hello
hello: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

I've verified that the command that the build script is running is identical to the one that I run myself. If I copy and paste the command and run it myself, the produced executable is again arm64.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When your build command doesn't include specific flags for which architecture to build for, the compiler tools provided by Apple, like `cc`, perform some kind of introspection based on the architecture of the *calling process*. That means that if your build system has yet to be natively compiled for `arm64`, you might see this behavior as the compiler will assume you want to build for x86_64!

You can demonstrate this by using the `arch` tool to run the `cc` executable in x86_64 mode:

```
% arch -x86_64 cc hello.c -o hello

% file hello
hello: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

As a work-around, you can introduce a shim compiler that always resets to the native architecture. Save this as `force-arm64-cc` and make it executable:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Note we are using arm64e because `cc` does not have an arm64 binary!
exec arch -arm64e cc "$@"
```

You can then use this shim in place of `cc`:

```
% CC=$PWD/force-arm64-cc ./my-build-system

% file hello
hello: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
```

---

The correct long term solution is to specify the target architecture when compiling:

```
% arch -x86_64 cc -arch arm64 hello.c -o hello

% file hello
hello: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
```

However, this currently produces a bogus executable when you *rebuild* the binary, which is quite common in an edit-compile-run cycle:

```
% ./hello
zsh: killed     ./hello
```

See also:

- [Why does my native arm64 application built using an x86_64 build system fail to be code signed unless I remove the previous executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64830671/155423)